# Using Lambda Function with find_if C++20

Tags: c++, c++20

I am getting a syntax error on the line
`if (auto result = ranges::find_if(height.begi` with a red squiggly line under `find_if`:

> no instance  of overloaded function matches the argument list

```
auto is_gt_or_eq = [height, i](int x) { height[x] >= height[i]; };

if (auto result = ranges::find_if(height.begin(), height.end(), is_gt_or_eq); result != height.end()) {
    std::cout << "First larger or equal to element in height: " << *result << '\n';
}
else {
    std::cout << "No larger or equal to element in height\n";
}
```

I found this similar code on cppreference, and it does run:

```
auto is_even = [](int x) { return x % 2 == 0; };

if (auto result = ranges::find_if(height.begin(), height.end(), is_even); result != height.end()) {
    std::cout << "First even element in height: " << *result << '\n';
}
else {
    std::cout << "No even elements in height\n";
}
```

I believe the error is in this line of code:

`auto is_gt_or_eq = [height, i](int x) { height[x] >= height[i]; };`

Comment: please [edit] this to contain a [mre] and include the error message you are getting,

Answer (score 2):

To start with, you forgot the `return` keyword for the `return` statement. So your lambda is returning void by default, thus not a valid predicate. The library won't allow you to call its function due to this mismatch.

Beyond that, `x` is (a copy of) the *element* of `height`, not an index of the container. There is no need to access the container again for the element in the lambda. So, the simplest fix is

```
auto is_gt_or_eq = [height, i](int x) { return x >= height[i]; };
```

There's also no need to constantly re-access `height[i]` in the lambda. It's not a bad idea to just capture that value instead.

```
auto is_gt_or_eq = [hi = height[i]](int x) { return x >= hi; };
```

Your lambda is now smaller, more inline-able and (to me at least) more readable.